# Cant see Overwrinting Cursor when i create new Line

Tags: java, swing, cursor

I'm trying to create an overwriting Cursor. I've got it except when I click an earlier line the caret disappears, then when I hit 'enter' for a new line it appears again.

what should I change in my Code to solve this issue?

here is my Caret Class:

```
public class Mycaret extends DefaultCaret {

    protected static final int MIN_WIDTH = 8;

    protected DefaultCaret dc = null;

    JTextComponent com = null;

    public Mycaret(int rate, DefaultCaret dc) {

        this.dc = dc;
        super.setBlinkRate(rate);
    }

    protected synchronized void damage(Rectangle r) {

        if (r != null) {

            try {

                JTextComponent comp = getComponent();
                TextUI mapper = comp.getUI();
                char dotChar = 0;
                if(comp.getText().length()>0){
                 dotChar = comp.getText().charAt(comp.getText().length()-1);
                }
                this.com = comp;

                Rectangle r2 = mapper.modelToView(comp, getDot() + 1);

                int width = r2.x - r.x;

                if (width == 0 ) {

                    width = MIN_WIDTH;


                }

                comp.repaint(r.x, r.y, width, r.height);

                this.x = r.x;
                this.y = r.y;
                this.width = width;
                this.height = r.height;

            }

            catch (BadLocationException e) {

            }
        }

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        char dotChar;

        if (isVisible()) {

            try {

                JTextComponent comp = getComponent();
                TextUI mapper = comp.getUI();

                Rectangle r1 = mapper.modelToView(comp, getDot());
                Rectangle r2 = mapper.modelToView(comp, getDot() + 1);

                g = g.create();
                g.setColor(comp.getForeground());
                g.setXORMode(comp.getBackground());

                int width = r2.x - r1.x;

                dotChar = comp.getText(getDot(), 1).charAt(0);

                if (width == 0  ) {
                    width = MIN_WIDTH;

                }



                g.fillRect(r1.x, r1.y, width, r1.height);
                g.dispose();

            } catch (BadLocationException e) {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

this is a Sample:

```
public class MyFrameSample extends JFrame {

    DefaultCaret caret=null;

    public MyFrameSample() {

        JTextArea text = new JTextArea(10,20);
        caret = new DefaultCaret();

        text.setCaret(new Mycaret(500, caret));
        add(text);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MyFrameSample();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that should be my question :)

Comment: I think I have a lead on this. I suggest that it happens because of a trap in `modelToView(comp, getDot() + 1)`. Notice that the carrot stops rendering *only at the end of non-empty lines which are not the last line*. These positions are exactly where `\n` would sit in in a document. Since the carrot takes the width between `getDot()` and `getDot() + 1`, and `\n` is invisible, you get an invisible carrot.

Comment: Yeah, it's indeed the newline character causing this. I will post some sort of answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the problem comes from newline characters (`\n`). When the caret is placed before `\n` in a non-empty line, it doesn't appear because it tries to take the width of a `\n`. Hence, I added a check for if a `\n` is at the same position the caret is.

**Mid-write edit:** @camickr figured out a better way by finding that *somehow* the width of `\n` is negative (anyone, why? See comments).

```
public class Mycaret extends DefaultCaret {

    protected static final int MIN_WIDTH = 8;

    public Mycaret(int rate) {

        super.setBlinkRate(rate);
    }

    protected boolean isBeforeNewLine() throws BadLocationException {

        PlainDocument doc = (PlainDocument) getComponent().getDocument();
        if (doc.getText(getDot(), 1).equals("\n"))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected synchronized void damage(Rectangle r) {

        if (r != null) {
            try {
                JTextComponent comp = getComponent();

                Rectangle r2 = comp.getUI().modelToView(comp, getDot() + 1);
                int width = r2.x - r.x;
                if (width == 0 || isBeforeNewLine()) {
                    width = MIN_WIDTH;
                }
                comp.repaint(r.x, r.y, width, r.height);

                this.x = r.x;
                this.y = r.y;
                this.width = width;
                this.height = r.height;
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        if (isVisible()) {
            try {
                JTextComponent comp = getComponent();

                g.setColor(comp.getForeground());
                g.setXORMode(comp.getBackground());

                Rectangle r1 = comp.getUI().modelToView(comp, getDot());
                Rectangle r2 = comp.getUI().modelToView(comp, getDot() + 1);
                int width = r2.x - r1.x;
                if (width == 0 || isBeforeNewLine()) {
                    width = MIN_WIDTH;
                }
                g.fillRect(r1.x, r1.y, width, r1.height);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

The `isBeforeNewLine` method get the text at the caret's position from the document. For a `JTextArea` it is a `PlainDocument`. If it's a `\n` then the width is set to `MIN_WIDTH`. This has to be done for both the `paint` and `damage` methods. It is also important to note that `\n` is the line separator for a `JTextArea` system-independently, but other text components might have it set differently.

**Notes:**

- When catching an exception, the least you can do is print the stack trace.
- I don't see a reason to create a new `Graphics` object in `paint`, use the one which is given.
- Use `@Override` when applicable.
- I just had to do some cleaning (refactoring), you might want to take something from this. I also changed the constructor since you don't need to pass a `DefaultCaret` to your class which extends it.

Comment: `somehow the width of \n is negative (anyone, why?).` That is because the next character after the "\n" will always be on the next line. (ie. the getDot() + 1, will get the character from the next line). The "x" offset of that character will always be 0.

Comment: @camickr Very nice! That explains the bold portion in my initial observation "*only at the end of **non-empty** lines which are not the last line*". If the line is empty then the width will be 0, otherwise it's the (negative) width of all the characters in the line.

Answer (score 3):

Based on @user1803551 observation I noticed that the width could be negative so I just changed your if condition to "<=" in the paint() and damage() methods:

```
if (width <= 0  ) 
{
    width = MIN_WIDTH;
}
```

Comment: a very Simple solution! Thanx